# LINQ conditional select from table and return multiple column as a single list

Tags: linq

The class names were renamed for reasons. But please assume this is how the class structure would look like.

```
public class Animal{
  public List<Cat> getCatsandKitten();
  {
   ...
  }
}

public class Cat {
    public Kitten kitten;
}

public class Kitten{
  public string name;
  public string nickname; 
}

//assume this returns a list of cats and populates each Cat class with kitten values. Also ignore any syntax issues.
var animals = getCatsandKitten();
```

Question:

How do I return a LINQ query that returns a list or array of values that contains the name or nickname of all kittens. 
Example: Get me a list of all kittens whose name or nickname contains Tom

Here's my query so far:

```
List<String> listOfKittens = animals
    .SelectMany(i => i.Cat
         .Where(m=>m.name.Contains("Tom") || m.nickname.Contains("Tom"))
         .SelectMany(s => new[] { s.name, s.nickname })
    );
```

This doesn't work because I'm returning both the columns(name and nickname) which meant that even if there's one match on a name, both values are returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `Kitten` is a `Cat`, or it will be a cat in future...They all have names, nicknames and other similar properties. For me, it looks like the single entity, and should be a tree-like structure: `public Cat[] Kittens { get; set; }`. IMHO.

Comment: Oh sorry that I gave a bad example. I changed the class names because of reasons but assume that this is the class structure in place. How would I query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order of `Where` and `SelectMany` and the query will work correctly: first get all the `name` and `nickname` attributes of all the kittens, then choose only those which contain the string `Tom`.

```
List<String> listOfKittens = animals
    .SelectMany(i => i.Cat
         .SelectMany(s => new[] { s.name, s.nickname })
         .Where(m => m.Contains("Tom"))    
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice. worked perfectly for my scenario. Thanks a lot Claudiu